# How to update the URL address without a redirect() in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, controller, codeigniter-2

In the example below, when I go the the URL: www.example.com/index.php/news/ it will call the method func1() but the URL will not change to www.example.com/index.php/news/func1.  It will remain as www.example.com/index.php/news/.

```
class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->func1();
    }

    public function func1()
    {
        echo "news item 1";
    }   
}
?>
```

I know that I can change the URL by using redirect('/news/func1') but is there any other way to update the URL when I call a method directly from method in the same Controller? Maybe using routing?

Any help will the appreciated.

Thank you.

V

Comment: The URL is something specified by the client.  If you are talking about changing the URL in the client's browser, then the only way to do that from a server-side standpoint is via a redirect.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I just wanted to know if there was any other way of doing it by maybe using a routing method but it looks like there isn't.

Comment: Have a look to URI routing. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

the change of url can be achieved through javascript.

1. Using window.location = url
   this will change the url and also refresh the browser
2. Using hash in the url www.example.com/#user1
   this will change the url into hash but will not refresh the browser.
3. If you want to change the url you mentioned.
   I use angular js in HTML5 mode to change the url in address bar.

Its better if you use jquery or any  frameworks like angular js, backbone js, knockout js

This will achieve you to change url in the browser without refresh